# Default value for jhipster entity field

Tags: entity, jhipster

The answer to this question  searched  in Google and  stackoverflow. On the right answer is not found. I created entity with jhipster. Now want to change, I want to add a new field with the default options. How to add default option for entity field with Entity.json file?
This piece of the desired location of the entity.json file:

```
    ....,
        {
            "fieldId": 3,
            "fieldName": "retry",
            "fieldType": "Integer",
            "????????": 10;
            "fieldValidateRules": [
                "required"
            ]
        }
    .....
```

instead the sign ????? need keywords that would give a default option

Comment: I don't think it is possible to set default value in jhipster entity json, otherwise it would be offered during entity creation magic.
I've checked the sources and haven't found anything similar:
https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/entity/index.js
There is a related question here:
https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/1189
...which points to the liquibase issue:
https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/issues/90

So I assume that you'll have to add default values manually in both your Java classes and Liquibase changesets. It is an approach I use.

Answer (score 4):

It is not currently supported, you have to edit the code by hand.

You can set the default value in EntityResource.java:createEntity or change the table specification in the liquibase changelog for the entity ([Liquibase - addDefaultValue](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/add_default_value.html)).